# How to connect to our distant server using a local hostname from dyn or -noip on local computer client instead of computer ip?

Tags: ssh, firewall, centos7, csf, cpanel

We using CSF as firewall on CPANEL. We blacklisted all countries except few.
Within the CSF there is a dyddns function allowing a FQDN to connect through...

We then set up a no-ip.com account with IP/Target being our local computer / ISP public IP.
Knowing that home IP changes, we were trying to get the firewall, and CPHulk to allow the FQDN hostname so that any time our local computer IP changes, we be able to still connect SSH, else we get locked out.

Upon research and discussion with noip support team, it seems, that this is possible, but unusual... for they said we were trying to use it in reverse...

So the question is, how do we get to connect automatically to the server from the local computer having its IP changing without adding manually the rule inside the server?

Is there a way, with anything else, we can use to automatically update the local client device inside the server remotely or some?

PS: Connection through SSH

Comment: Set up a jump host on a VPS which has static IP. Use that server to access your destination.

Comment: Yes, thank you. We might not been clear. We Actually did so with GCP. The issue, is that a regular user won't be able to do so. And our users are having dynamic IP that changes not only constantly, but even the ranges switch largely like from 27.*.** to 122.*.**

And for them, it becomes impossible to access their accounts, unless we manually allow in hosts.allow. So we were looking how to automatize it, taking in count the hosts.allow denies ALL but few manually added ip, and Csf automatically kicks out attempts failed 3 times...

Answer (score 0):

If the remote server's IP changes frequently, you can use NO-IP's agent to update your DNS entries. The agent will run in the background and will automatically update DNS records when the IP changes.

Linux Agent [here](https://www.noip.com/support/knowledgebase/installing-the-linux-dynamic-update-client/)

Windows Agent [here](https://www.noip.com/download?page=win)